# Creating a Grade Calculator using a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having difficulty understanding how to go about making my program. The program should look exactly like this:

```
Number of students: 3

Number of exams   : 3

Enter student's data (first name follow by exam scores):

Joe 85 88 93

Mike 90 100 97

Bill 50 68 73

Name E1     E2     E3     Grade


Joe  85     88     93     88.666666666667

Mike 90     100    97     95.666666666667

Bill 50     68     73     63.666666666664
```

I'm in an introduction to Java course, so I've just learned Arrays this week.

My code looks like this so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalcWithArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int students = 0;
        int exams = 0;

        System.out.println("Number of students: ");
        students = s.nextInt();
        String names[] = new String[students];

        System.out.println("Number of exams: ");
        exams = s.nextInt();
        int scores[][] = new int[students][exams];

        for (int i, j = 0;;) {
            System.out
                    .println("Enter student's data (first name followed by exams scores):");
            String studentnames = s.nextLine();
            studentnames = names[3];
            int e1 = s.nextInt();
            e1 = scores[0][0];
            int e2 = s.nextInt();
            e2 = scores[0][2];
            int e3 = s.nextInt();
            e3 = scores[0][3];

        }

    }
}
```

I'd love for some help with these arrays. I think I'm onto something with the way I'm trying to input. But once I get to the double array which my teacher said I would need to use I'm at a loss and I do not know how to go about inputting into the arrays. Any help is much appreciated.

Also the output of my program so far is:

```
Number of students: 3

Number of exams: 3

Enter student's data (first name follow by exam scores):

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at GradeCalcWithArrays.main(GradeCalcWithArrays.java:25)
```

I'm using Eclipse if that is a factor for how help is given also.

Comment: Array (`numbers`) with length = **3** has the following elements: `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]`, and `numbers[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start from 0. Since `name` is a `String` array which can hold 3 elements,the valid indexes are from 0-2 . You try to store a `String`(`studentnames`) in `name[3]` which is an invalid position. Hence,you get an `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception.

So your code should be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalcWithArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int students = 0;
        int exams = 0;

        System.out.println("Number of students: ");
        students = s.nextInt();
        String names[] = new String[students];

        System.out.println("Number of exams: ");
        exams = s.nextInt();
        int scores[][] = new int[student][exams];

        for (int i = 0;i<students; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter student "+ i+1 +" data (first name followed by exams scores):");
            names[i] = s.nextLine();

            for(int j=0;j<exams;j++)
            {
                scores[i][j] = s.nextInt();
            }

        }
     //Rest of your code to print the table goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: How to I go about fixing this problem then? I need to be able to enter my names in without this problem. By making my array `String students = new String[students];` Will this always be a problem?

Comment: @Daniel ,Sorry for the delay. I've edited the code.The problem is that when you do `String students = new String[students];` and if `students` is 3,then the valid locations are `students[0]`,`students[1]` and `students[2]` and not `students[3]`. This is because Array indexes starts from 0 not 1 as mentioned in my answer. You access `students[3]` which is an invalid location and hence,you get the ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.

Other than this,you must use a loop to accept input values as your code won't work when any number other than 3 is inputted

Comment: Thanks a bunch for helping me with that code. I'm wondering how I should go about outputting the code then? I don't know how to average my grade using the array and my program still won't work because my method of outputting is incorrect.

Comment: My code is as follows for the output. 
  `for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
   System.out.println(names[i]);
   for (int j = 0; j < exams; j++) {
    System.out.println(scores[i][j]);
    sum = sum + scores[i][j];
    gradeAverage = sum / scores.length;

   }
   for (int k = 0; k < students; k++) {
    System.out.println("Grade: " + gradeAverage);
  }
  
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Try this- `for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) { System.out.println(names[i]); for (int j = 0; j < exams; j++) { System.out.println(scores[i][j]); sum = sum + scores[i][j];  }gradeAverage = sum / scores.length; System.out.println ("Grade: " + gradeAverage); } ` and don't forget to accept the answer as it answered your question